# How to get correct result from my RSA Sign?

Tags: rsa, sha, javacard

I have written a piece of code to hash and rsa encrypt (somehow sign) a data sent to java card.

This is java card code:

```java
public class HelloWorldApplet extends Applet {

final static byte   APLET_CLA = (byte)0x80;
final static byte   INITIALIZE = (byte)0x00;
final static byte   SIGN = (byte)0x01;
final static byte   HASHVERIFY = (byte)0x07;
final static byte   GETHASH = (byte)0x08;

final static short SW_WRONG_DATA_LENGTH = 0x6300;
final static short SW_KEY_NOT_INITIALIZED = 0x6301;
final static short SW_KEY_IS_INITIALIZED = 0x6302;
final static short SW_KEY_IS_NOT_INITIALIZED = 0x6303;
final static short SW_INCORRECT_PARAMETER = 0x6304;

public static byte[] Message;
public static short message_len = 0;
public static short hashLen = 0;
public static short signLen = 0;
public static boolean key_initialization_flag256 = false;
public static boolean key_initialization_flag128 = false;

    // use unpadded RSA cipher for signing
    Cipher cipherRSA256 = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_RSA_NOPAD, false);
    Cipher cipherRSA128 = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_RSA_NOPAD, false);

    KeyPair rsaPair256 = new KeyPair(KeyPair.ALG_RSA_CRT, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_2048);
    KeyPair rsaPair128 = new KeyPair(KeyPair.ALG_RSA_CRT, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_1024);
    RSAPrivateCrtKey rsaKeyPriv256;
    RSAPrivateCrtKey rsaKeyPriv128;
    RSAPublicKey rsaKeyPub256;
    RSAPublicKey rsaKeyPub128;

    byte[] hashBuffer = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short)256, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);
    byte[] signBuffer = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short)256, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);

    byte[] dataBuffer = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short)256, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.ALG_SHA_256, false);

    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength)
    {
        Message = new byte[256];
        new HelloWorldApplet().register(bArray, (short) (bOffset + 1), bArray[bOffset]);
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu)
    {
        if (selectingApplet())
        {
            return;
        }

        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] == APPLET_CLA) {

            switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS]) {

                case INITIALIZE:
                    // generate a new key
                    initialize(apdu);
                    break;

                case SIGN:
                    // sign a given incoming message
                    sign_message(apdu);
                    break;

                case HASHVERIFY:
                    verify_hash(apdu);
                    break;

                case GETHASH:
                    get_hash(apdu);
                    break;

                default:
                    ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
            }
        } else {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }
    }

    public void initialize(APDU apdu)
    {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        switch(buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1]) {
            case 0x00: // gen 256 byte RSA key (P1=00)
                if (key_initialization_flag256)
                    ISOException.throwIt(SW_KEY_IS_INITIALIZED);
                rsaPair256.genKeyPair();
                rsaKeyPriv256 = (RSAPrivateCrtKey) rsaPair256.getPrivate();
                rsaKeyPub256 = (RSAPublicKey) rsaPair256.getPublic();
                key_initialization_flag256 = true;
                break;
            case 0x01: // gen 128 byte RSA key (P1=01)
                if (key_initialization_flag128)
                    ISOException.throwIt(SW_KEY_IS_INITIALIZED);
                rsaPair128.genKeyPair();
                rsaKeyPriv128 = (RSAPrivateCrtKey) rsaPair128.getPrivate();
                rsaKeyPub128 = (RSAPublicKey) rsaPair128.getPublic();
                key_initialization_flag128 = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    // P1=0 for modulus, P1=1 for exponent
    private void getPublicRSA(APDU apdu)
    {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        short length = 0;
        switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1])
        {
            case 0x00: // 256 byte RSA (P1)
                if (!key_initialization_flag256)
                    ISOException.throwIt(SW_KEY_IS_INITIALIZED);
                switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2]) {
                    case 0x00: // get the modulus (P2)
                        length = rsaKeyPub256.getModulus(buffer, (short) 0);
                        break;
                    case 0x01: // get the exponent (P2)
                        length = rsaKeyPub256.getExponent(buffer, (short) 0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        ISOException.throwIt(SW_INCORRECT_PARAMETER);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 0x01: // 128 byte RSA (P1)
                if (!key_initialization_flag128)
                    ISOException.throwIt(SW_KEY_IS_INITIALIZED);
                switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2]) {
                    case 0x00: // get the modulus (P2)
                        length = rsaKeyPub128.getModulus(buffer, (short) 0);
                        break;
                    case 0x01: // get the exponent (P2)
                        length = rsaKeyPub128.getExponent(buffer, (short) 0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        ISOException.throwIt(SW_INCORRECT_PARAMETER);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                ISOException.throwIt(SW_INCORRECT_PARAMETER);
        }
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, length);
    }


    public void sign_message(APDU apdu)
    {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        switch(message_len) {
            case 256:
                if(!key_initialization_flag256)
                    ISOException.throwIt(SW_KEY_IS_NOT_INITIALIZED);
                cipherRSA256.init(rsaPair256.getPrivate(), Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
                Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(Message, (short) 0, dataBuffer, (short) 0, message_len);
                pkcs1_sha(dataBuffer, (short) 0, message_len, hashBuffer); // 32 Bytes
                signLen = cipherRSA256.doFinal(hashBuffer, (short) 0, message_len, signBuffer, (short) 0); // 128 Bytes
                Util.arrayCopy(signBuffer,(short)0,buffer,(short)0,signLen);
                apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, signLen);
                break;
            case 128:
                if(!key_initialization_flag128)
                    ISOException.throwIt(SW_KEY_IS_NOT_INITIALIZED);
                cipherRSA128.init(rsaPair128.getPrivate(), Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
                Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(Message, (short) 0, dataBuffer, (short) 0, message_len);
                pkcs1_sha(dataBuffer, (short) 0, message_len, hashBuffer); // 32 Bytes
                signLen = cipherRSA128.doFinal(hashBuffer, (short) 0, message_len, signBuffer, (short) 0); // 128 Bytes
                Util.arrayCopy(signBuffer, (short) 0, buffer, (short) 0, signLen);
                apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, signLen);
               break;
            default:
                ISOException.throwIt(SW_WRONG_DATA_LENGTH);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void verify_hash(APDU apdu) {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        switch(message_len) {
            case 256:
                if(!key_initialization_flag256)
                    ISOException.throwIt(SW_KEY_IS_INITIALIZED);
                cipherRSA256.init(rsaPair256.getPublic(), Cipher.MODE_DECRYPT);
                hashLen = cipherRSA256.doFinal(signBuffer, (short) 0, message_len, buffer, (short) 0);
                apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, message_len);
                break;
            case 128:
                if(!key_initialization_flag128)
                    ISOException.throwIt(SW_KEY_IS_INITIALIZED);
                cipherRSA128.init(rsaPair128.getPublic(), Cipher.MODE_DECRYPT);
                hashLen = cipherRSA128.doFinal(signBuffer, (short) 0, message_len, buffer, (short) 0);
                apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, message_len);
                break;
            default:
                ISOException.throwIt(SW_WRONG_DATA_LENGTH);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void get_hash(APDU apdu) {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        Util.arrayCopy(hashBuffer,(short)0,buffer,(short)0,message_len);
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short)0,message_len);
    }

    // this function will leave tempBuffer with the data to be signed
    public void pkcs1_sha(byte[] toSign, short bOffset, short bLength,byte[] out)
    {
        md.reset();
        hashLen = md.doFinal(toSign, bOffset, bLength, out, (short) 0);
    }

}
```

the problem is, when I execute sign, verify and get hash commands, I desire to get same answers from verify and get hash. for some data the card answers correctly:

```java
mode_211
enable_trace
establish_context
enable_trace
enable_timer
card_connect
command time: 593 ms
select -AID E0E1E2E3E4E501
Command --> 00A4040007E0E1E2E3E4E501
Wrapped command --> 00A4040007E0E1E2E3E4E501
Response <-- 9000
command time: 31 ms
send_apdu -sc 1 -APDU 8000010000 // Gen RSA Key 128
Command --> 8000010000
Wrapped command --> 8000010000
Response <-- 6302
send_APDU() returns 0x80206302 (Unknown ISO7816 error: 0x6302)
command time: 0 ms
send_apdu -sc 1 -APDU 80040000802EEEEFF1115D0B637ED81CE45EA86984E37521409EB67A7D
9E7DE88CF3BDC693B2B4F05748F9E705B2FE1C1D8CB9288B32D06952B6193935DD14FF9C89B9860B
0B31B9BA3C4130A4CC1CEC5CE430A784525B10706EC971C25B4C45CA3C9D98ECDB0825DADB499F31
36CB7322DFC44F4DAD71133CA894A14446416021684B9029
Command --> 80040000802EEEEFF1115D0B637ED81CE45EA86984E37521409EB67A7D9E7DE88CF3
BDC693B2B4F05748F9E705B2FE1C1D8CB9288B32D06952B6193935DD14FF9C89B9860B0B31B9BA3C
4130A4CC1CEC5CE430A784525B10706EC971C25B4C45CA3C9D98ECDB0825DADB499F3136CB7322DF
C44F4DAD71133CA894A14446416021684B9029
Wrapped command --> 80040000802EEEEFF1115D0B637ED81CE45EA86984E37521409EB67A7D9E
7DE88CF3BDC693B2B4F05748F9E705B2FE1C1D8CB9288B32D06952B6193935DD14FF9C89B9860B0B
31B9BA3C4130A4CC1CEC5CE430A784525B10706EC971C25B4C45CA3C9D98ECDB0825DADB499F3136
CB7322DFC44F4DAD71133CA894A14446416021684B9029
Response <-- 9000
send_APDU() returns 0x80209000 (9000: Success. No error.)
command time: 78 ms
send_apdu -sc 1 -APDU 8001000000 // Sign Message
Command --> 8001000000
Wrapped command --> 8001000000
Response <-- BF9E0C7BE366F6E9B2E78A8E7E101F8BFEDB3497AE68A7B8FCCA158DBDB937E6F62
76971AC7BF2B96F4258D4745719CBC93DEEDD344B512BCB1B8D6105837FB2C5F983C92F01FF0D8B5
3B009DA8EB76124EB4BFE24D598144A6726926A2A84E7F0C8FD00CE13121CDF68A3B87D6DCD06ED4
6EB56DE0E073B3BDBF37EC9934BCD9000
send_APDU() returns 0x80209000 (9000: Success. No error.)
command time: 203 ms
send_apdu -sc 1 -APDU 8008000000 // get hash
Command --> 8008000000
Wrapped command --> 8008000000
Response <-- 0BDE2856A3EC1083EBE56E8FCC7294ED06A7B63633C438A6CCB3C3B1D1C88811000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000009000
send_APDU() returns 0x80209000 (9000: Success. No error.)
command time: 47 ms
send_apdu -sc 1 -APDU 8007000000 // verify hash
Command --> 8007000000
Wrapped command --> 8007000000
Response <-- 0BDE2856A3EC1083EBE56E8FCC7294ED06A7B63633C438A6CCB3C3B1D1C88811000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000009000
send_APDU() returns 0x80209000 (9000: Success. No error.)
command time: 78 ms
card_disconnect
command time: 203 ms
release_context
command time: 0 ms
```

but for some other data, I get incorrect respond from card and I don't know why this happens. here is the second data answering incorrectly:

```java
mode_211
enable_trace
establish_context
enable_trace
enable_timer
card_connect
command time: 577 ms
select -AID E0E1E2E3E4E501
Command --> 00A4040007E0E1E2E3E4E501
Wrapped command --> 00A4040007E0E1E2E3E4E501
Response <-- 9000
command time: 32 ms
send_apdu -sc 1 -APDU 8000010000 // Gen RSA Key 128
Command --> 8000010000
Wrapped command --> 8000010000
Response <-- 6302
send_APDU() returns 0x80206302 (Unknown ISO7816 error: 0x6302)
command time: 15 ms
send_apdu -sc 1 -APDU 8004000080335BE314CBC5C739DB41CCDD8FD0F53BB8F80E57DD3C18A9
091A715347BAFC5FD912A8973389BDFF05CF50A6E1B4716969A2C828A924D399D0A6A93DB0427666
7C9B623065D13192E5F372C8584A7111E74FC61923E1C1353DD1AE7D18991BEB3D83C49E6B756ABC
3359F9920E10BBEA24A999FB3E9A0CC1AC07E5C368F463DF
Command --> 8004000080335BE314CBC5C739DB41CCDD8FD0F53BB8F80E57DD3C18A9091A715347
BAFC5FD912A8973389BDFF05CF50A6E1B4716969A2C828A924D399D0A6A93DB04276667C9B623065
D13192E5F372C8584A7111E74FC61923E1C1353DD1AE7D18991BEB3D83C49E6B756ABC3359F9920E
10BBEA24A999FB3E9A0CC1AC07E5C368F463DF
Wrapped command --> 8004000080335BE314CBC5C739DB41CCDD8FD0F53BB8F80E57DD3C18A909
1A715347BAFC5FD912A8973389BDFF05CF50A6E1B4716969A2C828A924D399D0A6A93DB04276667C
9B623065D13192E5F372C8584A7111E74FC61923E1C1353DD1AE7D18991BEB3D83C49E6B756ABC33
59F9920E10BBEA24A999FB3E9A0CC1AC07E5C368F463DF
Response <-- 9000
send_APDU() returns 0x80209000 (9000: Success. No error.)
command time: 63 ms
send_apdu -sc 1 -APDU 8001000000 // Sign Message
Command --> 8001000000
Wrapped command --> 8001000000
Response <-- 9581924BA1F374489F83845FEEB7D71D71D3240C915CB1462434230982CA87A8AF3
0C2A716127C184E5DBB9EFF890A74A67967AC3EFE7E03FB433A3E52989459FDEF2CA8C19CD7BCD98
16434C4D84CF639F1D542F50B19BB56251BEA965F88168803F98906567CF1C2C6CE8B38999E16C50
49E2329F13156FA964F7477C07EF79000
send_APDU() returns 0x80209000 (9000: Success. No error.)
command time: 202 ms
send_apdu -sc 1 -APDU 8008000000 // get hash
Command --> 8008000000
Wrapped command --> 8008000000
Response <-- D9FE50E885FA4F2F85C70DC66FF42B5ABFAFB81820BF66F1967CB33D6E08AAE6000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000009000
send_APDU() returns 0x80209000 (9000: Success. No error.)
command time: 47 ms
send_apdu -sc 1 -APDU 8007000000 // verify hash
Command --> 8007000000
Wrapped command --> 8007000000
Response <-- 13AD6610CA13A7064193753BE50F268EC3F0D0AE8A5F079C0D40548835EAB0E9267
63B8EC02435CE8E126A4C97643D6BD2051E146CE353D351FF5FC58C0D2AD8BC5ADB40067F807EFE1
B2E1A37E027E6F50BA82DCE55DC37584F5941B6F29439234D97BE7612B03987E99C1F9F9A5A3B949
1E9758ECC7E02767D76B7C6C7A0B99000
send_APDU() returns 0x80209000 (9000: Success. No error.)
command time: 78 ms
card_disconnect
command time: 203 ms
release_context
command time: 0 ms
```

I will be so thankful if anyone can give me a hint or has had the same experience!!!

Comment: Why do you use `Cipher` for computing signature? Why don't you use `Signature` instead?

Comment: @vojta Thank you for answering me, the problem is java card I'm using which does not support `Signature` class.

Comment: We cannot help you unless you make the problem reproducible. You should at least clarify "but for some other data, I get incorrect respond from card" (which has been put in my unclear error descriptions on SO booklet, soon to be available).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I have put all my java codes and test data so that it can be completely reproduced. in the last code part the "some other data" is existing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hash is placed at the most significant end of the value, as RSA uses big endian encoding. This means that the value may be returned mod N (the modulus), which will result in a different value than that you put in.

Place the hash at the least significant end of the message and your code should run.

---

Notes:

- RSA without padding is **not** secure;
- Signature generation is **not** the same as encrypting a hash value with a private key if you consider padding, side channel attacks, performance etc. etc. etc..